# DateTime Model Binder, works for IE and Chrome but not for Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have created a DefaultModelBinder to work with DateTime

the format is "dd-MM-yyyy"

this DefaultModelBinder works fine with IE and Chrome,

but it does not work in Firefox ??

any help regarding this.

Update : {As Requested}

```
public class DateTimeBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var vpr = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (vpr == null)
        {
            return null;

        }

        var date = vpr.AttemptedValue;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
        {
            return null;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName));

        try
        {
            var realDate = DateTime.Parse(date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("en-GB"));

            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, new ValueProviderResult(date, realDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("en-GB")));

            return realDate;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeBinder());
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeBinder());
```

Update2: [Images Added]

Firefox : 
[image: Firefox Image]

This is the validation Issue in Firefox.

Internet Explorer :
[image: Internet Explorer Image]

NOTE : the request is not being sent to the SERVER, this is client-side validation from the MVC , which displays the error in FIREFOX.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: It could be that Firefox is sending a different Accept-Language causing the locale to be different from IE/Chrome. Could you show us a sample request for each browser?

Comment: We have had a similar problem. It turned out that it was a client side issue which may be the problem here. Can you show your view? Are you using any JavaScript and/or plugins. Our problem was with a Bootstrap date picker.

Comment: @PeterSmith : i am using Jquery UI datepicker, i tried by removing the DatePicker as well , still i am having Validation Issue in Firefox

Comment: Any help guys, waiting for your answers ??

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer to this question , umm its just BROWSER is using different culture my firefox is using culture as "English (en)" , but i am unable to sort the issue totally as i dont know how to disable this error.

i was thinking to use a hiddenfield for the Date and then a textbox so that user's may enter the date using the Jquery UI and during the submit i can process the Date and change it to yyyy-MM-dd.

Thanks for the help guys.